# "Exception: Non-zero exit code: 1" in Automated Build on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, auto-build

I ran into problems with setting up automated build on Docker Hub and I would be very grateful for your help.

I created Dockerfile and stored it on GitHub. I connected the GitHub account with Docker Hub one and created Automated Build (same repos on github and dockerhub: vokurka/docker-keboola-silverpop-ex/). I set up custom behavior:

[Custom behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPvnA.png)

And triggered the build. Everything went well to the point where it failed and I got this error message:

```
Encountered error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/common/highland/utils.py", line 35, in build_update_context yield File "/common/highland/monitor.py", line 137, in monitor if self.build_finished(): File "/common/highland/monitor.py", line 111, in build_finished raise Exception("Non-zero exit code: %r" % exit_code) Exception: Non-zero exit code: 1
```

And in UI said error looks like this:

[Error message in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRyBp.png)

Also, I got some log messages:

```
KernelVersion: 3.13.0-40-generic
Os: linux
BuildTime: Mon Oct 12 05:37:18 UTC 2015
ApiVersion: 1.20
Version: 1.8.3
GitCommit: f4bf5c7
Arch: amd64
GoVersion: go1.4.2
Step 0 : FROM keboola/base
```

By the way, the automated build for keboola/base is working well.

Also I tried several times to build the image at my computer and it works well.

So, I am little bit clueless here. Can someone please advice me what I can do to resolve this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear: my local Docker version is: 

`Docker version 1.8.3, build f4bf5c7`

Which should be the same as Docker Hub's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found answer. I think its more of a workaround than a solution, but what the hell.

I tried to debug the whole Dockerfile (commenting out one command after each other) till the point where I was left only with FROM and MAINTAINER. I was still running into the same issue.

So I changed FROM image to another and the problem was solved. The base image was more than 9 months old and probably built on some old version or something, I do not know.

The workaround here is just to change the FROM image or (if you have access) rebuild it.

Cheers!

Comment: Docker Hub support reaction (thanks for nothing!): "It looks like the base image used keboola/base is residing in Docker Hub V1 which was depcreated recently.
This has resulted the build to fail."